# Calculating XIRR in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to calculate XIRR of financial investments made over a period of time. Is there any function to do this in numpy, pandas or plain python?

[Reference: What is XIRR?](http://www.indiainfoline.com/article/research-articles/xirr-how-to-calculate-your-returns-38115077_1.html)

The accepted answer in the original question is not correct and can be improved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [financial python library that has xirr and xnpv function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919718/financial-python-library-that-has-xirr-and-xnpv-function)

Comment: I agree this is a possible duplicate. How do I delete this question? I see people are very 'down vote' happy and do not want more damage.

Comment: Once the question is answered it cant be deleted. Answerer put his time and effort to answer the question so.

Comment: @Bharathshetty I answered before I saw that, should I delete my answer here and move it to the linked one?

Comment: I don't think that would be appropriate. Your answer is clearly better than the one given in the original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an implementation taken from [here](https://github.com/peliot/XIRR-and-XNPV).

```
import datetime
from scipy import optimize

def xnpv(rate,cashflows):
    chron_order = sorted(cashflows, key = lambda x: x[0])
    t0 = chron_order[0][0]
    return sum([cf/(1+rate)**((t-t0).days/365.0) for (t,cf) in chron_order])

def xirr(cashflows,guess=0.1):
    return optimize.newton(lambda r: xnpv(r,cashflows),guess)
```

Comment: As it might be confusing that the `cashflows` variable is not used in `xnpv`, at the moment (2018-02-13) the method looks a bit different on the repo. Can you update your answer?

Comment: No need to sort the cashflows by time.

Answer (score 10):

Created a package for fast XIRR calculation, [PyXIRR](https://github.com/Anexen/pyxirr)

It doesn't have external dependencies and works faster than any existing implementation.

```py
from datetime import date
from pyxirr import xirr

dates = [date(2020, 1, 1), date(2021, 1, 1), date(2022, 1, 1)]
amounts = [-1000, 1000, 1000]

# feed columnar data
xirr(dates, amounts)

# feed tuples
xirr(zip(dates, amounts))

# feed DataFrame
import pandas as pd
xirr(pd.DataFrame({"dates": dates, "amounts": amounts}))
```

Answer (score 0):

This implementation calculates the time delta once and then vectorizes the NPV calculation.  It should run much faster than @pyCthon's solution for larger datasets.  The input is a pandas series of cashflows with dates for the index.

### Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

def xirr2(valuesPerDate):
  """  Calculate the irregular rate of return.
  valuesPerDate is a pandas series of cashflows with index of dates.
  """

  # Clean values
  valuesPerDateCleaned = valuesPerDate[valuesPerDate != 0]

  # Check for sign change
  if valuesPerDateCleaned.min() * valuesPerDateCleaned.max() >= 0:
    return np.nan

  # Set index to time delta in years
  valuesPerDateCleaned.index = (valuesPerDateCleaned.index - valuesPerDateCleaned.index.min()).days / 365.0

  result = np.nan
  try:
    result = optimize.newton(lambda r: (valuesPerDateCleaned / ((1 + r) ** valuesPerDateCleaned.index)).sum(), x0=0, rtol=1e-4)
  except (RuntimeError, OverflowError): 
    result = optimize.brentq(lambda r: (valuesPerDateCleaned / ((1 + r) ** valuesPerDateCleaned.index)).sum(), a=-0.999999999999999, b=100, maxiter=10**4)

  if not isinstance(result, complex):
    return result
  else:
    return np.nan
```

### Tests

```
valuesPerDate = pd.Series()
for d in pd.date_range(start='1990-01-01', end='2019-12-31', freq='M'):
  valuesPerDate[d] = 10*np.random.uniform(-0.5,1)
valuesPerDate[0] = -100

print(xirr2(valuesPerDate))
```