# Is there a python library to calculate time weighted returns based on portfolio weights and stock prices?

Tags: python

I have a question in regards to calculating Time-weighted returns in Python.
Is there any library in python to calculate time-weighted returns?
Or is there any way to calculate time weight using the portfolio weightage and daily stock price?

I have actually written a code but would want to seek advice on this question before I continue.

Thanks

Using these assumptions for my question.

**Assumption1:**

Period 1: $5K (20%) @ 5,000 shares at $1 each

Period 2: $10K (Period 1+2 = 60%) @ 5,000 shares at $2 each

Period 3: $10K (100%)

**Assumption 2:**

Period 1: Share price at $1, (Jan price)

Period 2: Share price at $2, (Aug price)

After searching in google, most solutions are calculated using the amounts. Assuming calculation in Dec 31 and share price is $1.3 at Dec 31

Period 1: ((5,000 shares * $2)-5000 shares *$1)/$5000 = (10,000-5000)/5000 = 100%

Period 2: (10,000 shares * $1.3)- ((5,000 shares * $2)+$10,000)/((5,000 shares * $2)+$10,000) = ($13,000-($20,000))/$20,000 = -35%

Time weighted for 2 period = ((1.1)*(0.65)) -1 = -0.29%

```
ticker = "TOT"
df_period = [] # To store dataframes of each period
time_wgt_period = [] # To store time period values
product = 1 

def absoluteReturn(DF):

    absoluteReturn = ((DF["Adj Close"][-1]-DF["Adj Close"][0])/DF["Adj Close"][0])

    return absoluteReturn

# Get all different investment periods 
period1 = pdr.DataReader(ticker, data_source='yahoo', start=datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 26), end=datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 25))
period2 = pdr.DataReader(ticker, data_source='yahoo', start=datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 26), end=datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 8))
period3 = pdr.DataReader(ticker, data_source='yahoo', start=datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 9),  end=datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 17))
period4 = pdr.DataReader(ticker, data_source='yahoo', start=datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 18), end=date.today())

#Append all dataframe periods in a list so I can loop to call the CAGR function
df_period.append(period1)
df_period.append(period2)
df_period.append(period3)
df_period.append(period4)

# Using for loop to call absolute return function and plus 1 to get time weighted values
for i in df_period:
    time_wgt_period.append(absoluteReturn(i)+1)

#weights = np.array([0.20, 0.20, 0.20, 0.40,])
#np.dot(annualReturn_period, weights)    

# Using for loop to get nultiply each time period value
for k in time_wgt_period:
    #print("Product value: " + str(product) + "*" + str(k))
    product = k*product


print ("Time Weighted Return for " +ticker+": "+str(round((product-1), 2) * 100) + "%")
```

Comment: Questions that ask for software/library recommendations are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site because any answer is generally just an opinion.. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept called IRR which will give you an equivalent percentage for a series of cashflows. In your case just two.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_rate_of_return

If you have a stock you have to be mindful of the sign e.g.:

```
stock_a 100 2022-01-01 -100 # buy
stock_b 100 2022-01-01 120 # sell or 'artificial sell for calculation purposes'
```

I hope this is helpful. You can play with the concept using Excel or Google sheets, as these functions linked follow how the spreadsheets implement the answer.

See [financial python library that has xirr and xnpv function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919718/financial-python-library-that-has-xirr-and-xnpv-function)