# Calculate XIRR for mutual fund transactions in Python

Tags: python, xirr

I knew that my question is answered here ..[financial python library that has xirr and xnpv function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919718/financial-python-library-that-has-xirr-and-xnpv-function)..

```
def xirr(transactions):
    years = [(ta[0] - transactions[0][0]).days / 365.0 for ta in transactions]
    residual = 1
    step = 0.05
    guess = 0.05
    epsilon = 0.0001
    limit = 10000
    while abs(residual) > epsilon and limit > 0:
        limit -= 1
        residual = 0.0
        for i, ta in enumerate(transactions):
            residual += ta[1] / pow(guess, years[i])
        if abs(residual) > epsilon:
            if residual > 0:
                guess += step
            else:
                guess -= step
                step /= 2.0
    return guess-1
```

when i execute above code for fund transactions, i am getting negative residual in 1st iteration.
guess=0.5-0.5=0
Due to this,I am getting **zerodivisionerror** in next iteration.
Why am i getting negative residual ..how to deal with this?/
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this in the following way: used `guess+1` in the pow function, and removed the `-1` part from the result:

```py
def xirr(...):
    while ...:
        for ...:
            residual += ta[1] / pow(guess+1, years[i])
    ...
    return guess
```

I also ran into performance issues since this code is written in the pure python. So I created the [faster version](https://github.com/Anexen/pyxirr) using the rust under the hood. It works more than 100 times faster than python implementation.