# Receiving an Overflow Error when implementing XIRR function in python

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, finance

Hi mighty StackOverflow,
I have been following this [post's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919718/financial-python-library-that-has-xirr-and-xnpv-function) approach to implement an XIRR function in my small personal finance project and have been running into an Overflow Error.

This is the original code:

```
def xnpv(rate, values, dates, daycount=365):
 daycount = float(daycount)
 d0 = dates[0]  # or min(dates)
 # NB: this xnpv implementation discounts the first value LIKE EXCEL
 # numpy's npv does NOT, it only starts discounting from the 2nd
 return sum([vi / (1.0 + rate) ** (di - d0).days / daycount for vi, di in zip(values, dates)])

def xirr(values, dates, daycount=365, guess=0, maxiters=10000, a=-100, b=1e10):
 # a and b: lower and upper bound for the brentq algorithm
 cf = np.array(values)

 if np.where(cf < 0, 1, 0).sum() == 0 | np.where(cf > 0, 1, 0).sum() == 0:
  # if the cashflows are all positive or all negative, no point letting the algorithm
  # search forever for a solution which doesn't exist
  return np.nan

 try:
  output = scipy.optimize.newton(lambda r: xnpv(r, values, dates, daycount),x0=guess, maxiter=maxiters, full_output=True, disp=True)[0]
 except RuntimeError:
  try:

   output = scipy.optimize.brentq(lambda r: xnpv(r, values, dates, daycount),
                                  a=a, b=b, maxiter=maxiters, full_output=True, disp=True)[0]
  except:
   result = scipy.optimize.fsolve(lambda r: xnpv(r, values, dates, daycount),
                                  x0=guess, maxfev=maxiters, full_output=True)

   if result[
    2] == 1:  # ie if the solution converged; if it didn't, result[0] will be the last iteration, which won't be a solution
    output = result[0][0]
   else:
    output = np.nan

 return output
```

What I have tried is to set everything as a `Decimal` but this only shifted a type error into the line of `scipy.optimize.newton` as there seems to be internal multiplication with the float 1.0 which I can not prevent.

For any tips on how to avoid the Overflow error in the xnpv function or anything else, I would be very grateful. Best J

Comment: I would use better bounds a and b. If the sum of cash flows is positive, you can set a=0. b can be set to something reasonable as well. A good starting point is also helpful.

Comment: Could you provide an input example? you can also try to use https://github.com/Anexen/pyxirr/.